# Failed to allocate memory: 8 (NetBeans)

Tags: android, netbeans, jvm

Today, when I tried to run an app in NetBeans on a 2.3.3 platform, it shows me that:

```
Failed to allocate memory: 8

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

and the Emulator doesn't start.

This is for the first time when I see it, and google has no asnwers for this, I tried even with 2 versions of NetBeans 6.9.1 and 7.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was in the amount of ram I had specified for the virtual machine, and it was 1024MB, now I have 512MB and it is ok, now I need to find how to improve this amount of ram, 512 is not so much, and the machine is a little bit laggy.